# Can't override Context API with useState updating function in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, themes, react-context, state-management

Hi I currently building an NextJS app. I want to implement the dark and light theme so I create a theme context which will store the app theme states(darkmode and lightmode).

#### My current solutions

1. I use true-false data type to represent the dark and light mode.
2. true is for dark and false is for light. Default is false.
3. To toggle the theme, I create a function for it
4. I create context provider component directly in the same file. It's called `ThemeContextProvider`.
5. To update the context data, I'm using `useState` as seen below.
6. With that logic, I pass the context value with the `useState` data I have in the provider.
7. I override the `toggleTheme` which is from the `context` with `setTheme` from the `useState`.
8. I'm triggering the toggleTheme fn in the navigation bar(toggle button).

#### My expectation

1. Whenever I click the toggle button, the `toggleTheme` fn from the context is not actually overrided with the `setTheme` from the `useState` so the theme data in the context will not be updated.
   Can anybody tell me why this happened?
   If you guys get confused please take a look at my codes below

Here's my theme-context code

```js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const ThemeContext = createContext({
  //false: lightmode, true: darkmode
  theme: false,
  toggleTheme: () => {},
});

export const ThemeContextProvider = (props) => {
  //false: lightmode, true: darkmode
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(false);

  const themeHandler = () => {
    setTheme(!theme);
    console.log("toggled!");
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{
        theme,
        toggleTheme: themeHandler,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ThemeContext;
```

Here's my toggle button

```
<button onClick={() => toggleTheme}>Toggle theme</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function

```
<button onClick={() => toggleTheme()}>Toggle theme</button>
```